# how to serialize a cfc instance

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, railo

The `<cfwddx>` tag can easily be used to serialize and deserialize complex data types such as arrays, structs and queries, but not cfc instances.

What's the best way to serialize and later deserialize a cfc?

Comment: Or, hm. Maybe this isn't reasonable at all since the data inside the component is hidden.

Comment: Probably the best way to handle this would be to add a method that gives you a memento of the data for the current CFC instance. I use this method frequently when I need to pass data back and forth as JSON.

Comment: Right on. I was thinking about this too. I actually have such a method, getInstanceData() .... so I'll just use that and serialize the result, I think. Thank you Scott!

Comment: What exactly are you looking to serialize?  The methods and properties?

Comment: Thinking about it further Dan, I think it depends. Basically we have a debugging tool where we capture the complex data in the db for later review and reporting and it operates with wddx serialization. We regularly pass structs, arrays and queries to it, but I realized it doesn't handle cfc instances. I think in certain circumstances the cfc metadata would be valuable to capture and in other cases, the internal state of the instance would be valuable. So I guess the calling code will need to decide.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the nature of a CFC instance (data hiding), the wddx process cannot look "inside" of it in order to serialize it.

However, you do have two options for CFC instance serialization, depending on what you're looking to accomplish.

1. If you want to serialize the internal state of your CFC instance, you should just add a method within your CFC which returns the variables scope of the CFC instance. You can then simply serialize the response from calling that method. `getMemento()` or `getInstanceData()` should work. -- Thanks Scott Stroz!
2. If you want to serialize the metadata (properties and methods) of the CFC instance, you could use ColdFusion's build in function `getComponentMetadata()` and serialize the result of that call. -- Thanks Dan Bracuk!

Answer (score 1):

Check out `ObjectSave()` and `ObjectLoad()`, but IMO they can be risky if the serialized data is to be loaded in a different version of CF down the road.